# How to enable same standard-js linting in Vue3 <template> expressions as in <script> in same .vue file?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, eslint, standardjs

I use eslint and standard-js rules in my Vue3 project. Standard rules are properly linted in `<script>` tags in .vue files, and in standalone .js files, but not in expressions within the `<template>`.

For example, if I run `npm run lint` on this template

```
<template>
  <div v-if="1>  2">{{ 1>  2?1:2 }}</div>
</template>
<script>
const a = 1>  2?1:2
</script>
```

it will be auto-linted to

```
<template>
  <div v-if="1> 2">{{ 1> 2?1:2 }}</div>
</template>
<script>
const a = 1 > 2 ? 1 : 2
</script>
```

There is some linting happening in the `<template>` (two spaces become one in `v-if` and `{{}}`), but not the same/full standard-js linting as in the `<script>` section of the same .vue file below. What do I have to do/configure so that the same rules apply inside the `<template>` too?